# Can ''onamae'' be used in the middle of a sentence?

Tags: grammar

What is your name is usually given as:

Onamae wa nan desu ka?

or

Anata no namae wa nan desu ka?

My question is whether or not the following is ever used:

Anata no onamae wa nan desu ka?

I understand fully the meaning of the honorific 'o' and I also recognise that a word beginning with 'o' is a bit awkward after 'no', i.e. '' no onamae ''. But that is irrelevant to my question.

Will a Japanese person ever say ''Anata no onamae wa nan desu ka?''

Comment: It does sound a bit unnatural, but it is grammatically correct.

Comment: ^Jack, えっ? Which part of it is unnatural??

Comment: @Chocolate, I think that JACK's point is the contrast between あなた (direct pronoun, AFAIK _not so polite_) and **お** 名前 with the honorific prefix (_polite_). Wouldn't 「あなたの名前は」 (without お)  and 「お名前は」(without あなた) be more natural than 「あなたのお名前は」?

Comment: あなたのお名前 reminds me of トニー谷 (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VCyFwgXV228).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Kantura as far as I know, there is nothing awkward with using the honorific "o" after "no" [e.g. related to the ongoing typhoon 19 recovery efforts, asking your neighbor, who you know has parents living in the affected areas, asking e.g. "Tanaka-san no ojikka wa daijoubu desu ka".]

While some Japanese might be offended if being asked "Anata no [o]namae wa nan desu ka?", asking that from a foreigner would most cases be simply about assuming that the foreign-looking person needs to be addressed to in very clear wording, [rather than e.g. about clear racism]. When asking this, the person talking to the foreigner may be nervous and "just in case" adds the "o". Also, as the population in Japan is getting older, you sometimes hear the "Anata no onamae wa nan desu ka?" also in e.g. in public offices. But, if speaking on the phone, e.g. if one calls a company providing some services to him/her, and one wants to know the name of the customer service person who attended the call, a Japanese would normally simply say "shitsurei desu ga" [literally "I am being rude"], when "we" would say "can I have your name, please". In the above context both "anata no name ha nan desu ka" and "anata no onamae ha nan desu ka" would sound awkward / aggressive / intruding

Comment: `ojikka` × お実家 ○ **ご**実家